# Match pattern in a file and print the matching word (not the whole line) in second column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to match the pattern "SHM" in a file containing like the below information and print the word matching the pattern.

```
LOCALZONE01     ASHM001002003VOL01
                BSHM001002003VOL02
                CSHM001002003VOL03
                DSHM001002003VOL03_DUP
                ESHM001002003VOL04
                FSHM001002003VOL05
                GSHM001002003VOL06_
                HSHM001002003VOL07
```

I have tried to use awk to print the 2nd column:

```
grep "SHM" <filename.txt> | awk -F" " '{print $2}'

ASHM001002003VOL01
```

If I try to print column 1, it’s giving me the below output:

```
LOCALZONE01
BSHM001002003VOL02
CSHM001002003VOL03
DSHM001002003VOL03_DUP
ESHM001002003VOL04
FSHM001002003VOL05
GSHM001002003VOL06_
HSHM001002003VOL07
```

Below is my desired output. How can I get it?

```
ASHM001002003VOL01
BSHM001002003VOL02
CSHM001002003VOL03
DSHM001002003VOL03_DUP
ESHM001002003VOL04
FSHM001002003VOL05
GSHM001002003VOL06_
HSHM001002003VOL07
```

Comment: Technically, I could answer your question with `printf '%s\n' ASHM001002003VOL01 BSHM001002003VOL02 CSHM001002003VOL03 DSHM001002003VOL03_DUP ESHM001002003VOL04 FSHM001002003VOL05 GSHM001002003VOL06_ HSHM001002003VOL07`, because you say “a file containing below information” and not “a file containing information *like* the below”; i.e., you make it sound like the data in the question is ***the*** data you want to process, and not just ***an example**.*  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I’m not really serious, but I say this to raise the point that you will rarely get answers that are better than your question, and many answer-writers focus on the example data in the question, and not the question as a whole.  Please [edit] your question to clarify what properties your input will and will not have, and give examples *that illustrate* the possibilities.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  For example, will the last word on *every* line contain ```SHM```?  (If so, why even bother stating that as a factor in the question?)  Will the first line always have two words?  If so, will the first word always be `LOCALZONE01`?  Will it always be 11 characters long?  Will it always be followed by 5 blanks?  Will the second word always start at the 17th character position?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Will every line after the first always have exactly one word?  Will *it* always start at the 17th character position?  Does the “second” (final) word have a maximum length? … … Are the whitespace characters spaces, tabs, or a combination? … … How do you define “word”?  For example, if your file has ```QSHM003.14159PIES```, do you want to see that entire string, or just `QSHM003` (because the **`.`** is a word separator, and so `14159PIES` is a separate word)? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  In particular, if any posted answer works for the sample data in your question, but not your real file, please [edit] your question to show the manner of input that the answer doesn’t handle.   (Do this in addition to leaving a comment on the answer.)   If an answer doesn’t work for your real data, that’s not a reason to ask a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output you want is always the last field in the file, try this

```
awk '{if ($NF ~ /SHM/) {print $NF}}' _input_file_
```

Comment: more idiomatic awk is "condition {action}": `awk '$NF ~ /SHM/ {print $NF}'`

Answer (score 5):

If you have GNU grep available,

```
grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]_]*SHM[[:alnum:]_]*' < filename.txt
```

If not, you could ask awk to loop through the fields of each line, looking for SHM:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /SHM/) print $i }' < filename.txt
```

Comment: I don't think that `grep` expression requires GNU `grep`, nor `-E`. (sorry, that was before I spotted the `-o`, but `-E` would not be needed, right?)

Comment: Correct, @Kusalananda, as-is. I suppose it could/should be tightened up to require 1-or-more alnum's after the "SHM" text, in which case it would need `-E` for clarity, if not functionality, as `In GNU grep, there is no difference in available functionality between basic and extended syntaxes.`

Comment: @jeff I used the awk version. Thanks. I am redirecting the output to another file where i am using these hostnames to capture df output. Surprisingly the redirected output seems to have an extra character "^M" in the redirected output. I filtered it out using sed i.e `sed -e "s/^M//" filename` but it seems like it is removing the letters starting with M as well. Any thoughts pls

Comment: Got it . i used `sed 's/\r//g'` to filter it out

Comment: jeff, I want to print only the 2nd column in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Because the first column of your example data has no entries beginning with row #2 and going forward, you'll have to parse it as `fixed-width` columns. You can do this:

```
$awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "16 40"} /SHM/ { print $2}'
ASHM001002003VOL01
BSHM001002003VOL02
CSHM001002003VOL03
DSHM001002003VOL03_DUP
ESHM001002003VOL04
FSHM001002003VOL05
GSHM001002003VOL06_
HSHM001002003VOL07
```

Comment: I'd suggest a simplification: `awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "16 40"} /SHM/ { print $2}'`

Comment: @JeffSchaller. Your solutions are always elegant! I will update the answer ;-)

Comment: I used to chain grep awk and sed together, until I learned awk a bit better!

Comment: @Jeff Schaller I can use this it is not always certain the field widths are in the same way mentioned above meaning the first word can have more than 20 characters in some files. If i use the above one, sometimes i am seeing the output as  `04  SHM001002016VOL01`

Comment: @xrkr. The command above can handle files contain fixed-width columns. If the width is not equal between the columns, then you would need to convert the file to fixed-width columns. After then, pipe the output to the previous command, something like: `awk -F, '{printf("%20s %20s %15s\n", $1, $2, $3)}' <FILE.txt> | awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "16 40"} /SHM/ { print $2}'
`

Comment: There seems to be some problem. I am seeing only the numbers `                                     
                                     01
                                     02
                                     02
                                     03
                                     04
                                     05
                                     06_
                                     07_
                                     09
                                     10
   `
And then the output is not as intended `002003VOL01
            002003VOL02`

Comment: @xrkr. Would you please post new question. Maybe your issue is different. Please provide an example!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this as follows using `Perl`:

```
perl -lne 'print for /\w*SHM\w*/g' input-file.txt

perl -lane 'print for grep /SHM/, @F' input-file.txt # assuming SHM fields r alphanumeric
```

Or, with the `sed` editor in a **POSIX**-*compatible* manner, assuming all lines atleast one SHM

```
sed -ne '
    s/[[:alnum:]_]*SHM[[:alnum:]_]*/\
&\
/;s/.*\n\(.*\n\)/\1/;P;/\n$/!D
' input.txt
```

**Output:**

```
ASHM001002003VOL01
BSHM001002003VOL02
CSHM001002003VOL03
DSHM001002003VOL03_DUP
ESHM001002003VOL04
FSHM001002003VOL05
GSHM001002003VOL06_
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $2}' filename && awk 'NR>1' filename | sed 's/[[:space:]]*//g'
```

Output:

```
ASHM001002003VOL01
BSHM001002003VOL02
CSHM001002003VOL03
DSHM001002003VOL03_DUP
ESHM001002003VOL04
FSHM001002003VOL05
GSHM001002003VOL06_
HSHM001002003VOL07
```

That prints the second column on the first line, the following lines, and then removes whitespace to fix the formatting and return the output you want.

Comment: you don't need to call awk multiple times: `awk 'NR == 1 {print $2} NR > 1 {print $1}'`. This can even be collapsed, but at the expense of readability: `awk '{print $(NR == 1 ? 2 : 1)}'`

Comment: @glennjackman True, but it works just the same and it's roughly the same length with the removal of the whitespace.

Comment: I guess it's the principle of calling one program versus calling 3 to achieve the same result.

Comment: @glennjackman I understand, but in his case, it really doesn't affect anything. If it were a script that was doing more work then I, too, would prefer your solution because it wouldn't call as many programs and it would be less tedious.

Comment: By the way, the downvote here doesn't make any sense. A downvote is needed when the answer just doesn't work. Mine does work. it may require more than some of the other answers but it gives the desired output and doesn't make things any worse.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but that's not the only reason to downvote: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote -- I might downvote an answer if I think the answerer's approach is wrong, not necessary if the actual code is buggy.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm not accusing you as if it were you, I'm sure you've have done it yesterday. I'm addressing whoever might have done it. I've admitted that your way is a bit better but I'm just not of the mind that mine deserves a downvote. It may call `awk` once more and use a `sed` but it isn't terrible. If it were calling more programs that were resource heavy or if it were a script and I kept running the same exact command over and over again instead of assigning it to a shell variable then I'd understand and I'd change it. I just don't see where it's making things horrible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

awk '{head=substr($0,1,16);mypat=substr($0,17,23);if (mypat~/SHM/). {print mypat}}' filename